# get key name inside of it`s value function

Tags: javascript, object

How do I get key names from it`s value nameless function?

What would be /*some code */ that get 'foo'

```
var obj = {
    foo: function () {
             console.log('Error found in ' + /* some code */);
         }
};

obj.foo(); // get 'Error found in foo'
```

Comment: You cannot necessarily assume access to [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) so you can't do this, but if you can assume it, do a `for..in` over `this` testing for `arguments.callee`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By iterating over the properties of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) using [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) you can test against [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)

```
var o = {
    foo: function () {
        var k, found, pname = 'unknown';
        for (k in this) if (this[k] === arguments.callee) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        if (found) pname = k;
        console.log('Error found in ' + pname);
    },
    bar: "something else"
};

o.foo(); // Error found in foo
```

Please note that `arguments.callee` **is forbidden in strict mode** by ES5 spec.

In this case you would need a named function expression,

```
var o = {
    foo: function fizzbuzz() {
        var k, found, pname = 'unknown';
        for (k in this) if (this[k] === fizzbuzz) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        if (found) pname = k;
        console.log('Error found in ' + pname);
    },
    bar: "something else"
};

o.foo(); // Error found in foo
```

Finally,

- If you are doing things where you can't guarantee enumerability `for..in` will not necessarily work, take a look [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)
- If you've changed your `this`, there is no way for the function to know what you want without passing it a reference to your object in another way

Comment: @JunhoKim [**ES6 is the same as ES5 on this**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arguments-exotic-objects); forbidden in strict mode. Arrow functions don't give you an `arguments` so you can't use it for them either. Best use a named function expression.